# Prove that $F(N/2;N,x)+F(N/2;N,1-x)=1$ where $F$ is binomial CDF

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

I have the following claim:

$$F(N/2;N,p)+F(N/2;N,1-p)=1$$ where $F$ is a binomial CDF with exactly $N/2$ successes in $N$ total trials, and with each trial having success probability $p$.

Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a bernoulli rv with parameter $1-p=P(X=1)$ can be re-interpreted as $p=(X=0)$ Extending this to the binomial rv with parameter $p:B(p,N)$ (i.e., sum of N i.i.d bernoulli rv's), your claim is equivalent to asking "What is the probability that a N tosses yields *at most* $\frac{N}{2}$ heads OR at most $\frac{N}{2}$ tails". Since the number of heads and tails adds to $N$ at most one of these statements will always be true, so $P(B(p,N)\leq \frac{N}{2} \cup (N-B(p,N))\leq \frac{N}{2})=P(B(p,N)\leq \frac{N}{2})+P((N-B(p,N))\leq \frac{N}{2})=1$ (since the two events are disjoint.

Now, by noting that $B(1-p,N)=N-B(p,N)$ (i.e., they are mirror images of each other)

$P(B(p,N)\leq \frac{N}{2})+P((N-B(p,N))\leq \frac{N}{2})=P(B(p,N)\leq \frac{N}{2})+P(B(1-p,N))\leq \frac{N}{2})=1\;\;\;\square$

Comment: $B(1-p,N)=N-B(p,N)$ seems to be a bit unclear although I understood what you mean.For $B(p,N)$ and $B(1-p,N)$ being two different r.v.s they don't have to add up to $N$ for each realization.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören your question is about the distribution *functions* not random variables. $B(p,N)$ refers to the probability mass function, not a random variable. I was using rvs to intuitively show why the *functions* $B(p,N)$ and $B(1-p,N)$ are mirrors of one another.

Comment: I know you are right but then I don't understand what does $P(B(p,N)\leq N/2)$ mean.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören sorry, I was being inconsistent with my notation. Just focus on the fact that if you look at the functions $F(p,N)$ and $F(1-p,N)$ that they are mirrors. That will answer your question.

Comment: Is it true or false to say that $B(1-p,N)=N-B(p,N)$ in probability and $B(p,N)$ and $B(1-p,N)$ are binomial random variables?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I don't think so...that formulation only applies to the actual functions, not to two independent rvs.

Comment: Let $X\sim B(p,N)$ and $Y\sim B(1-p,N)$. Then I guess the distribution of Y and the distribution of $N-X$ will be the same.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören yes, exactly. That's why the sum comes out to 1.